# What is the best way to output a PDF for Fogra from InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, color-profile

I'm working in the US and so always am using SWOP in my color settings in InDesign. The current project I've got will be printed in the EU and the printer wants Fogra for the PDF I deliver for print.

My question is: in InDesign, should I change the Working Spaces color setting to Fogra from SWOP? Or is it better to just output the PDF to Fogra and leave InDesign as SWOP? Or is there some other recommended way to do this? TIA

Comment: There is no one workflow. If you want to know "best" then you ought to define what metrics you prefer to optimize. I mean if there was a definitive Best setting they wouldnt give you options (work life is not like videogames, there are inherently no reason to add red herrings in software)

Comment: Okay, if there are different workflows, what are the advantages/disadvantages of them?